# Adding Dynamic Link to Custom Field

Tags: hyperlink, suitescript2.0

I'm new to Netsuite Suitescript.
I have created a custom field which stores the sales order on the purchase Order. I am trying to make the field dynamic so when user clicks on it, it will take you to the Sales order

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard NetSuite field at the Purchase Order level named "Created From". It is repopulated with the Sales Order # if a Purchase Order is created from a Sales Order.  If this field is not sufficient, ensure the field you created is type = List/Record and stores a value.  If you cannot store a value, please share more details on the custom field you created (type, defaulting, sourcing, filtering, etc.).

080421 addition: 
I see.  I can think of 3 ways to address this. (1) update the mechanism that creates POs, if it's a script instead of record.create use record.transform. This will populate the native NS field going forward.  (2) create a custom transaction body field that will list the Sales Order Transaction record.  Then you will have to set this value manually, or via script.  or (3) update existing field to house the internal id of the SO, and create a custom transaction body field that is a hyperlink that has a default value as: 'https://XXXX.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/salesord.nl?&id='||{fieldIdContainingSOInternalId}

Comment: Thanks Martha, I'm not using standard functionality, so Create From field is not being populated. I tried to use the field on creation of the PO but it would not update the field. I then created a custom Standard Free Form Text field and updated it with the related Sales Order. User then requested it as Dynamic Link back to the SO.

Comment: @Renzo if this answer was helpful for you, then mark it as the right one. Otherwise, you can help other people by posting the right answer yourself.

Comment: Hi B.Assem, yes was helpful I used option 3. Sorry, i'm new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Hi @Renzo : you need to mark the answer as the right answer (the green check image)